# I cant get data to display in a DBGrid in my program. I am a grade 11 student that has just started learning delphi

Tags: database, delphi-10.4.2

When creating a program to work with a database in delphi, the DBGrid will not display data even though the database is connected to the data module.

I am following this video to create my program:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwb0wv6IJqA

I have followed everything perfectly and I have tried on my brothers computer to see if it is a hardware issue.
When I get to the step at 9:03 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwb0wv6IJqA&t=543s) the data source shows up but no information pops up into the database. Here is what his database looks like after selecting the data source[IT Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDEKe.png) and this is what mine looks like [my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C46O.png).

I have tried to save the program on every single step, i have the database inside the program files and next to the exe file. I have also made sure that the database is a .mdb. [database in the program files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYD44.png).

I am not sure if the problem is because he is using delphi 2010 and I'm using delphi 10.4 and if there are any extra steps that I must do for this to work but every other video besides this with databases have worked exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

please, check `tblCD.Active = true` in object inspector
[image]

Comment: This worked tysm